# Are we [licensed] for all this?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request, tag-synonym-request

I think [license-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/license-key) and [product-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/product-key) should be synonyms. There's also [software-activation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-activation).

I also don't see why the 12 [volume-license](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/volume-license) questions aren't just tagged with [license](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/license) given you can get volume licensing on software and OS.

Comment: if you downvote, please leave a comment on which suggestion you disagree with (license & product keys) or (volume & license).

Comment: For your title, I'd suggest **"Obtaining a [license] to kill"**.

Comment: To kill tags that is @SeldomNeedy

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It really comes down to granularity.  [license-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/license-key) and [product-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/product-key) are really the same thing, but software-activation is a process and should stay separate.

[volume-license](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/volume-license) could be grouped into [license-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/license-key).  I am concerned that it might not be discoverable enough and that it might be different enough to warrant its own tag.  Usually those looking for volume licensing are IT profestionals who are going to need a very different answer than home users using single licensees.

My vote is to combine [license-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/license-key) and [product-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/product-key), but leave the other two.

Comment: @Raystafarian I forget the rules for low volume tags, but I think it is a [unique topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) from license-key.  While many volume license users will have a rep or contact they can get help from, I never did when I was managing ours.  Plus, reps usually take a while to get back to you.  SE sites are to collect important info so it can be easily found and referenced.  As SU has more answers professionals need, they will be more likely to ask and answer questions on the site.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm just disagreeing is all - no downvote. Sometimes volume licensing agreements are unique to an organization.

Comment: @Raystafarian I just wanted to make sure my stance was clear, including your rep suggestion.  All good. :)